# PostgreSQL update certain value from another table.

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables 
og and new, and I only want to update certain rows' geom value.

The og table.

```
des| geom
----------
 A |  1
 B |  2
 C |  3
 D |  4
 E |  5
 F |  6
 G |  7
 H |  8
```

And the new table

```
description| geom
------------------
         A |  0
         B |  0
         C |  500
         D |  0
         E |  700
         F |  0
         G |  0
         H |  300
```

I want to update only the "C", "E" and "H" rows' geom.

So the og table would be like this.

```
des| geom
----------
 A |  1
 B |  2
 C |  500
 D |  4
 E |  700
 F |  6
 G |  7
 H |  300
```

my SQL script can only update one row, how can I update multiple rows at one script.

```
UPDATE og t0  
SET 
  geom = t1.geom 
FROM 
  new t1 
WHERE 
  t0.des = t1.description
AND t0.des = 'C'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`in`:

```
AND t0.des in ('C','E','H')
```

or

```
and t1.geom <> 0
```